# Prevent xs collapse just for one item of navbar - Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a way I can prevent "sign in with twitter" button from collapsing at xs resolution **without recompiling** bootstrap.css ? Maybe keep "sign in" button in same navbar div with "previous" and "next" buttons but copy x coordinate from "search" button above with javascript or some other css hack...?

Edit: here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/43Lcy/

Here is that code:

```
      <div class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm left-offset">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Previous</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Next</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div style="margin-right: 10px; float:right;" class="navbar-form navbar-right">
          <img class="left-offset" height="29px" width="29px" style="margin-top:1px;" src="./images/avatar.png" />
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Sign in with Twitter</button>
      </div>
```

And here is how it looks like at the moment.

[a busy cat http://www.dodaj.rs/f/N/N3/V084DII/skrin.jpg](http://www.dodaj.rs/f/N/N3/V084DII/skrin.jpg)

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Look at the pic. "Sign in with twitter" button should be where it's written red "here".

Comment: Put the entire issue and what you've tried in a Fiddle. http://css-tricks.com/seriously-just-make-a-jsfiddle/

Comment: Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/43Lcy/ I also edited post with link.

Comment: @ImeIme Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/43Lcy/1/

Comment: This line solved it `.navbar-left {float: left !important;}` . You might want to write answer with explanation what you did (how float:left css made button actually floating right), so I can mark it as solving answer.

Answer (score 1):

The fiddle you created is using BS 2, but it looks like you want to use version 3, so I made this Bootply: http://bootply.com/106036

I would remove the inline styles that are overriding the Bootstrap CSS and put whatever you don't want to collapse in `navbar-header`...

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">  
    <div class="navbar-header">

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <form class="navbar-form pull-left">
          <div class="form-group" style="display:inline;">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>

      <div class="pull-right">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-btn btn btn-default">Sign in with Twitter</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-btn btn btn-default">Prev</button>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-btn btn btn-default">Next</button>
      </div>

    </div>
</nav>
```

### http://bootply.com/106036

Comment: I want to keep that one collapse between "search" and "previous" buttons. Check @Sujrits css fiddle, it does exactly what I want.